# Uncaught TypeError: Função JS

Tags: javascript

Podem me ajudar a entender onde esta o erro?

```
function atualizaLista(id_leilao) {
    if (id_leilao) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'id_leilao=' + id_leilao,
            global: false,
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.histories.length; i++) {
                    biddingusername = data.histories[i].history.username;
                    biddingprice = data.histories[i].history.bprice;
                    biddingtime = data.histories[i].history.time;

                    document.getElementById('bid_user_name_' + i).innerHTML = biddingusername;
                    document.getElementById('bid_price_' + i).innerHTML = 'R$' + biddingprice;
                    document.getElementById('bid_time_' + i).innerHTML = biddingtime;
                }
            }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });          // fim ajax
    } // fim if
}
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**

Informa que é nessa linha:

```
document.getElementById('bid_user_name_' + i).innerHTML = biddingusername;
```

**HTML:**

```
<tr class="producthisrow">
    <td align="center" id="bid_user_name_<?= $q; ?>"></td>
    <td align="center" id="bid_price_<?= $q; ?>"></td>
    <td align="center" id="bid_time_<?= $q; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Pra ele o campo html que vc esta tentando povoar nao existe. qd o js esta rodando.. esse elemento nao existe no DOM. Procura informacao sobre o append.  Pode ler esse site: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null-at-print-scriptjs29-at-scriptjs32

Comment: @IsraelZebulon Todos os campos existem no HTML.

Comment: Seria de grande ajuda se [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/279996/edit) e colocar o *HTML* !

Comment: @wmsouza Ele repete as linhas com uma sequencia, ficando: bid_user_name_0, bid_user_name_1, bid_user_name_2

Comment: @dvd Não entendi a forma que você falou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o código não está encontrando o elemento pelo `id` dentro do laço `for`.

Para evitar o erro aplicar o `innerHTML` apenas ao elementos que existem na página, coloque as linhas:

```
document.getElementById('bid_user_name_' + i).innerHTML = biddingusername;
document.getElementById('bid_price_' + i).innerHTML = 'R$' + biddingprice;
document.getElementById('bid_time_' + i).innerHTML = biddingtime;
```

Dentro de um `if` para verificar se o `document.getElementById('bid_user_name_' + i)` existe:

```
if(document.getElementById('bid_user_name_' + i)){
   document.getElementById('bid_user_name_' + i).innerHTML = biddingusername;
   document.getElementById('bid_price_' + i).innerHTML = 'R$' + biddingprice;
   document.getElementById('bid_time_' + i).innerHTML = biddingtime;
}
```